# Relations with two foreign key to one primary key

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have a table with relations two foreign key to one primary:

```
public function getFromUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'from_user_id']);
}
public function getToUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'to_user_id']);
}
```

And I have to do

```
$var = Posts::find()->select([
            ...
        ])->with([
            'fromUser' => function (yii\db\ActiveQuery $query) {
                $query->select(['id', 'concat(...) AS name']);
            },
            'toUser' => function (yii\db\ActiveQuery $query) {
                $query->select(['id', 'concat(...) AS name']);
            }
        ])->asArray()->all();
```

And all works fine. But is can somehow to do these relations (realization) better?

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: @rob006 defined

Answer (score 0):

These are separate relations, you cannot declare it differently (at least not without hacking `ActiveRecord` relations logic). If these are "twin" relations and you don't want to repeat the same things twice, you may write helpers methods which will do the same operation for both relations.

For example custom `ActiveQuery` for `Post` model:

```
class PostQuery extends ActiveQuery {

    public function withUsers(?Closure $callback = null) {
        if ($callback === null) {
            return $this->with(['fromUser', 'toUser']);
        }

        return $this->with([
            'fromUser' => $callback,
            'toUser' => $callback,
        ]);
    }
}

class Post extends ActiveRecord {

    // ...

    /**
     * @return PostQuery
     */
    public static function find() {
        return Yii::createObject(PostQuery::class, [static::class]);
    }
}
```

And then use `withUsers()` method to apply conditions to both relations:

```
$var = Post::find()
    ->select([
        // ...
    ])
    ->withUsers(function (yii\db\ActiveQuery $query) {
        $query->select(['id', 'concat(...) AS name']);
    })
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Or:

```
$var = Post::find()->withUsers()->all();
```